# Query to count the number of institutions with the word 'college' in their name

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am trying up to write a query to counting the number of institutions with the word "college" in their name.

My database is called `Scorecard` and the column name is `instnm`.

Comment: Hint try [like](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-like/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the StackOverflow comunity,

I am assuming that the table name is `Scorecard` and the column name is `instnm` and you have no indexes.

The query becomes

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Scorecard WHERE instnm like '%college%';
```

The term *college* is probably case sensitive, unless you set the opposite.